# Traer mas de un elemento de una tabla en un select, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

En un formulario tengo un select que selecciona un usuario una DB usuario, con un select:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="" class="col-form-label">Usuario</label>
     <select class="custom-select" id="usuario_id">
       <option value=""></option>
          <?php $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT id_usuario,
                                                    concat(p_nombre,' ',p_apellido)as nombre, 
                                                    n_documento,
                                                    telefono
                                              FROM usuarios");
             while ($valor = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
             {?>
            <option value="<?php    echo $valor['nombre_u'];?>">
             <?php echo $valor['nombre']; ?>
           </option>
          <?php
           } ?>
     </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

La cosa es que en este formulario quisiera traer mas de un dato de este usuario y que los campos del formulario referentes a id, n_documento y telefono (por ejemplo) se rellenaran con la informacion de este usuario y poder mandarlas con el isset para llenar otra DB que es la que alimenta este formulario.
El script funciona como se espera, al seleccionar el nombre del usuario me trae el id y lo inserto en la tabla nueva sin problemas.

Comment: Puedes agregar la otra información que necesites, sea en otros elementos adicionales (`select -> option`, `input` ...)  o en un único `select -> option` usando atributos `data-`, te toca a ti decidir lo que prefieres. Aunque me pregunto si hay algo que justifique tener datos repetidos en bases de datos y/o tablas distintas... ¿por qué no centralizar los datos en un solo lugar?

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua, era simplemente utilizar el id del usuario y a partir de ahi en el select hacer las consultas para ver los demas datos.

Comment: Ya, por eso me extrañaba que quisieras trasladar todo a otro sitio, no le veía sentido. Con el ID puedes relacionar tablas y evitar redundancia de datos.